Monitoring Gunicorn Queue Time for Autoscaling with Datadog
I manage a Django application served by Gunicorn, which uses synchronous workers, deployed on Kubernetes and using AWS ELB as a load balancer. For APM and log management, we utilize Datadog.
In scenarios of high traffic, the synchronous workers of Gunicorn become busy, leading to a situation where incoming requests exceed the processing capacity, causing requests to queue up as no workers are available immediately. I'm looking to monitor these Gunicorn queue times to optimize autoscaling triggers and maintain performance.
Could anyone confirm if my understanding of request queuing in Gunicorn with synchronous workers is accurate? Additionally, how can I effectively monitor these queue times using Datadog, or any other methods? What specific metrics or logs should we look at to detect and address this queuing issue effectively?
Thanks in advance for your insights!
Note:

I've explored Datadog documentation but did not find it the proper metrics to use: https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/gunicorn/
I've contacted the Datadog support team. They were not able to help tackle this question and offer a solution.
When using PaaS with APM such as Scout APM, it is possible to access the "Queue Time". Article: https://judoscale.com/guides/request-queue-time

